ERROR in ./node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/index.js
When i wrote css code using ant and react-slick i got error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/index.js (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs/lib/index.js) Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): SyntaxError
(1:1) C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Máy tính\Reactjs\my-app\node_modules@ant-design\cssinjs\lib\index.js Unknown word

1 | "use strict";
| ^
2 |
3 | var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault"); 
I can't figure out where it comes from in my project
Can anyone help me?
My github have code for me : https://github.com/dinhlan17122011/thuchanh

enter image description here
